# Nested Linked Lists and Functions in C

Tags: c

I have a linked list which stores two integer variables called height and weight.

```
struct measurement {
    int height;
    int weight;
    struct measurement *next;
};
```

I also have another linked list which has measurement nested within it.

```
struct person {
    struct measurement *measurement;
    struct person *next;
};
```

I have already created a main function which takes in inputs for weight/height and passes it onto the function to add it into the "person" linked list.

```
int add_data(struct person *person, int height, int weight) {
    struct person *add = (struct person *)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    add->measurement = (struct measurement *)malloc(sizeof(struct measurement));
    int check = 0;
    if (height < 250 && height > 0 && weight > 0) {
        check = 1;
    }
    if (check == 1) { 
        add->measurement->height = height;
        add->measurement->weight = weight;
        add->measurement = add->measurement->next;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
// This function returns an integer if the measurements are successfully added.
```

However, when it seems like the function does not move onto the next node as intended. When testing it out, I am able to print out the integer's of height and weight respectively but every time the function is ran again it seems to overlap the previous measurements.
(This program is to record the growth of a person overtime, that is why there are multiple measurements for height and weight)

Comment: The definition for `struct dimensions` is missing

Comment: sorry, it was mean't to be measurement.

Comment: Is there a reason you never use `struct person *person`? Did you mean to put the created `measurement` into the `person` pointer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo over here:

```
add->measurement = add->measure->next;
```

and it should be:

```
add->measurement = add->measurement->next;
```